# Can anyone tell me why I cant access this code from outside of it's project?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, api

I found some code online for image searching/recognition and since I do not know barely any csharp I put it in a class and built it. Now when I try to access it from a vb project it does not show up. Even after it is referenced I cannot actually access it. I am geussing because the functions are not shared, and as I understand "Static" in C# is the same as "Shared in vb.net. Although when adding it in I get errors. Can anyone confirm if this is the issue why  I can't access it?? Same goes for when I referenced this proejct from my vb.net project I could not access the classes either.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ImageRecognition
{
class LockedFastImage
{
    private Bitmap image;
    private byte[] rgbValues;
    private System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData;

    private IntPtr ptr;
    private int bytes;

    public LockedFastImage(Bitmap image)
    {
        this.image = image;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
        bmpData = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, image.PixelFormat);

        ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
        bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * image.Height;
        rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
    }

    ~LockedFastImage()
    {
        // Try to unlock the bits. Who cares if it dont work...
        try
        {
            image.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns or sets a pixel of the image. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">x parameter of the pixel</param>
    /// <param name="y">y parameter of the pixel</param>
    public Color this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            int index = (x + (y * image.Width)) * 4;
            return Color.FromArgb(rgbValues[index + 3], rgbValues[index + 2], rgbValues[index + 1], rgbValues[index]);
        }

        set
        {
            int index = (x + (y * image.Width)) * 4;
            rgbValues[index] = value.B;
            rgbValues[index + 1] = value.G;
            rgbValues[index + 2] = value.R;
            rgbValues[index + 3] = value.A;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Width of the image. 
    /// </summary>
    public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return image.Width;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Height of the image. 
    /// </summary>
    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return image.Height;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the modified Bitmap. 
    /// </summary>
    public Bitmap asBitmap()
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
        return image;
    }
}

class ImageChecker
{

    private LockedFastImage big_image;
    private LockedFastImage small_image;
    /// <summary>
    /// The time needed for last operation.
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan time_needed = new TimeSpan();

    /// <summary>
    /// Error return value.
    /// </summary>
    static public Point CHECKFAILED = new Point(-1, -1);

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor of the ImageChecker
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="big_image">The image containing the small image.</param>
    /// <param name="small_image">The image located in the big image.</param>
    public ImageChecker(Bitmap big_image, Bitmap small_image)
    {
        this.big_image = new LockedFastImage(big_image);
        this.small_image = new LockedFastImage(small_image);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the location of the small image in the big image. Returns CHECKFAILED if not found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x_speedUp">speeding up at x achsis.</param>
    /// <param name="y_speedUp">speeding up at y achsis.</param>
    /// <param name="begin_percent_x">Reduces the search rect. 0 - 100</param>
    /// <param name="end_percent_x">Reduces the search rect. 0 - 100</param>
    /// <param name="begin_percent_x">Reduces the search rect. 0 - 100</param>
    /// <param name="end_percent_y">Reduces the search rect. 0 - 100</param>
    public Point bigContainsSmall(int x_speedUp = 1, int y_speedUp = 1, int begin_percent_x = 0, int end_percent_x = 100, int begin_percent_y = 0, int end_percent_y = 100)
    {
        /*
         * SPEEDUP PARAMETER
         * It might be enough to check each second or third pixel in the small picture.
         * However... In most cases it would be enough to check 4 pixels of the small image for diablo porposes.
         * */

        /*
         * BEGIN, END PARAMETER
         * In most cases we know where the image is located, for this we have the begin and end paramenters.
         * */

        DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;

        if (x_speedUp < 1) x_speedUp = 1;
        if (y_speedUp < 1) y_speedUp = 1;
        if (begin_percent_x < 0 || begin_percent_x > 100) begin_percent_x = 0;
        if (begin_percent_y < 0 || begin_percent_y > 100) begin_percent_y = 0;
        if (end_percent_x < 0 || end_percent_x > 100) end_percent_x = 100;
        if (end_percent_y < 0 || end_percent_y > 100) end_percent_y = 100;

        int x_start = (int)((double)big_image.Width * ((double)begin_percent_x / 100.0));
        int x_end = (int)((double)big_image.Width * ((double)end_percent_x / 100.0));
        int y_start = (int)((double)big_image.Height * ((double)begin_percent_y / 100.0));
        int y_end = (int)((double)big_image.Height * ((double)end_percent_y / 100.0));

        /*
         * We cant speed up the big picture, because then we have to check pixels in the small picture equal to the speeded up size 
         * for each pixel in the big picture.
         * Would give no speed improvement.
         * */

        //+ 1 because first pixel is in picture. - small because image have to be fully in the other image
        for (int x = x_start; x < x_end - small_image.Width + 1; x++)
            for (int y = y_start; y < y_end - small_image.Height + 1; y++)
            {
                //now we check if all pixels matches
                for (int sx = 0; sx < small_image.Width; sx += x_speedUp)
                    for (int sy = 0; sy < small_image.Height; sy += y_speedUp)
                    {
                        if (small_image[sx, sy] != big_image[x + sx, y + sy])
                            goto CheckFailed;
                    }

                //check ok
                time_needed = DateTime.Now - begin;
                return new Point(x, y);

            CheckFailed: ;
            }

        time_needed = DateTime.Now - begin;
        return CHECKFAILED;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding the `public` access modifier to your classes, which are thus automatically declared as `internal`. Fix it and everything should work.

Example:

```
public class LockedFastImage { /*Your code...*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified any access specifier with your class, thus by default your class is `internal` that is why you can't access it outside the assembly.

[For classes and structs Access Modifier - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in
>   other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can
>   be either public or internal. **Internal is the default if no access
>   modifier is specified.**

```
public class LockedFastImage 
{....
```

You may see [Access Modifier C# - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

**internal**

> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly,
>   but not from another assembly.